# Error in running Apache OFBiz using eclipse IDE

Tags: java, ofbiz

I have a project on OFBiz framework. I have imported and set the runtime configuration but when I try to run it, I get the errors below.

In the run configuration window, we have several tabs, with these settings:

- Main tab: Main class is set to org.ofbiz.start.Start
- Arguement tab: VM arguments: -Xms128M -Xmx512M -jar ofbiz.jar > runtime\logs\console.log
- JRE: the JRE is installed.
- Class Path: I have added the ofbiz.jar file
- Source: I have added the OFBiz project
- Environment: I have added the environment var JAVA_HOME

This is the exception I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot load configuration properties : org/ofbiz/base/start/>.properties
    at org.ofbiz.base.start.Start$Config.getPropertiesFile(Start.java:494)
    at org.ofbiz.base.start.Start$Config.readConfig(Start.java:524)
    at org.ofbiz.base.start.Start.init(Start.java:78)
    at org.ofbiz.base.start.Start.main(Start.java:406)
```

What could be the cause?

Comment: You will need to provide more information(regarding the steps done etc.). But from the first look, I suspect the property files name is incorrectly configured. You don't have property file names like ">.properties"

Comment: in run configuration window we have several tabs<
1 Main tab :
--- Main class is set to org.ofbiz.start.Start
2 Arguement tab :
--- VM arguements have given : -Xms128M -Xmx512M -jar ofbiz.jar > runtime\logs\console.log
3 JRE :
the jre installed.
4 Class Path:
--- Have added the ofbiz.jar file
5 Source.
---- have added the OFBiz project
6 Environment.
---- Have added the environment var JAVA_HOME

these are the settings done in run configuration window.

later  when i tried to run as i mentioned i got the mentioned error.

Answer (score 1):

I think this part "> runtime\logs\console.log" is confusing OFBiz. For some reason Eclipse is passing these and bunch of other parameters to the main method/
Instead try this

-Xms128M -Xmx512M -jar ofbiz.jar start

Answer (score 0):

I've created a document though which you can setup OFBiz in STS / Eclipse IDE.
Here you go https://github.com/pashtika/OFBiz